# How to rewrites to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have tried to work on this tutorial which is about creating Cloud Run environment and serving a page on Firebase Hosting.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run#python

The Cloud Run part works as it says on the page, but [Firebase Hosting part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run#direct_requests_to_container) is not working for me. It get 404 error when I access the `PROJECT_ID.web.app/` and `PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com/`
I updated the Firebase CLI version to make it the latest version.

```json
"hosting": {
  "public": "public", // I need to add this since I got an error without specify public dir
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "run": {
      "serviceId": "helloworld",  // "service name" (from when you deployed the container image)
      "region": "us-central1"     // optional (if omitted, default is us-central1)
    }
  } ]
}
```

Does anyone have the same issue as well?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you have missed a step in the set up stage. There is a helpful guide that includes the [steps for implementation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting#implementation_path) you might want to have a look at.

You can also test your container locally with Docker to rule out any obvious issues first. If you need to [install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) you can follow this guide.

To run your container locally you can do:

```sh
PORT=8080 && \
docker run -p 9090:${PORT} -e PORT=${PORT} gcr.io/myproject/my-image:latest
```

Replace `myproject/my-image:latest` to the project where the container image is stored on Google Cloud Platform

The `PORT` environment variable specifies the port your application will use to listen for `HTTP` or `HTTPS` requests. This is a requirement from the Container Runtime Contract. In this example, we use port 8080.

```sh
http://localhost:9090
```